# How to Combine two Queries Which has different where clause and Group by different Date Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Tried In Many ways Ended up with Errors.
I have Two Queries like below:

```
SELECT EnqDate AS Date, COUNT(ID) AS EnqueryCount
FROM Enquiry 
 WHERE EnqDate BETWEEN 'June 24 2017' AND 'June 29 2017'
 GROUP BY EnqDate
order by Date

SELECT FirstTryDateTime AS Date, COUNT(ID) AS FirstCallCount
FROM Enquiry 
 WHERE FirstTryDateTime BETWEEN 'June 24 2017' AND 'June 29 2017'
 GROUP BY FirstTryDateTime
order by Date
```

Which Gives the Below Result:

[image]

And I Need to Combine those two Queries and require a result like below:

[image]

Please Can Anyone help me in this?

Comment: Can you also give us the input data that generated the results you mention in your post?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL combining two counts that use same columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44648578/mysql-combining-two-counts-that-use-same-columns)

Comment: @HoneyBadger This case tries to combine queries having a *different* `GROUP BY` field.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, So? The principle is the same.

Comment: Yes u r right giorgos. i tried searching first. then posted the question. this case is different.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Not exactly. If the `GROUP BY` field is common, then there is no need to either `UNPIVOT` or `JOIN`. We can directly use *conditional aggregation*.

Answer (score 0):

I would just join the two query-results via the column Date:

```
SELECT A.Date
      ,A.EnqueryCount
      ,B.FirstCallCount
  FROM
    (
    SELECT EnqDate AS Date, COUNT(ID) AS EnqueryCount
    FROM Enquiry 
     WHERE EnqDate BETWEEN 'June 24 2017' AND 'June 29 2017'
     GROUP BY EnqDate
    order by Date
    ) A
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT FirstTryDateTime AS Date, COUNT(ID) AS FirstCallCount
    FROM Enquiry 
     WHERE FirstTryDateTime BETWEEN 'June 24 2017' AND 'June 29 2017'
     GROUP BY FirstTryDateTime
    order by Date
    ) B
  ON A.Date = B.Date
```

Comment: left join? result will be incorrect if right side of your query has result but left doesn't have

Comment: @Vecchiasignora: Well, its just based on the data which is posted in the question. really depends on the data. so a FULL JOIN might be the better way

Comment: @Sindhoor: could you explain me, why it is not working?

Comment: I would start with a calendar table to make sure all dates are selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH enquery AS (
SELECT EnqDate AS Date, COUNT(ID) AS EnqueryCount
FROM Enquiry 
GROUP BY EnqDate
) 
SELECT Date, EnqueryCount, COUNT(ID) AS FirstCallCount
FROM Enquiry 
JOIN enquery ON Date = FirstTryDateTime
WHERE Date BETWEEN 'June 24 2017' AND 'June 29 2017'
AND FirstTryDateTime BETWEEN 'June 24 2017' AND 'June 29 2017'
GROUP BY Date, EnqueryCount
ORDER BY Date
```

Side note, you should try and avoid using Oracle reserved words (i.e. date) as column names.

Comment: as the question is about, MS SQL Server, the Oracle reserved words won't harm him. but anyway he should avoid using reserved words in general

Comment: Yes. i follow your guidance from next

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`UNPIVOT`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) to unpivot the table, then apply conditional aggregation to get the result you want:

```
SELECT Val,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DateField = 'EnqDate' THEN ID END) AS EnqueryCount, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DateField = 'FirstTryDateTime' THEN ID END) AS FirstCallCount
FROM (
   SELECT ID, EnqDate, FirstTryDateTime
   FROM Enquiry
   WHERE (EnqDate BETWEEN '2017-06-24' AND '2017-06-29') OR
         (FirstTryDateTime BETWEEN '2017-06-24' AND '2017-06-29')) AS p
UNPIVOT (Val FOR DateField IN ( EnqDate, FirstTryDateTime)) AS unpvt
GROUP BY Val
ORDER BY Val
```

Comment: This is working Partially but not giving total count because it is taking date and also time.

Comment: @Sindhoor This is not an issue directly related with the problem of OP. You can solve the issue simply by converting `DATETIME` fields to `DATE` type.

Comment: Yes But getting error by doing that. i am trying CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), EnqDate) is this right way?

Answer (score 0):

Just combine `Union All`, `Sum()` and `Subquery` like this

```
SELECT Sel.Date, sum(EnqueryCount) as EnqueryCount, sum(FirstCallCount) as FirstCallCount  
FROM
    (SELECT EnqDate AS Date, 1 AS EnqueryCount, 0 AS FirstCallCount
    FROM Enquiry 
     WHERE EnqDate BETWEEN 'June 24 2017' AND 'June 29 2017'
    union all
    SELECT FirstTryDateTime AS Date, 0 AS EnqueryCount, 1 AS FirstCallCount
    FROM Enquiry 
     WHERE FirstTryDateTime BETWEEN 'June 24 2017' AND 'June 29 2017') Sel
group by Sel.Date
order by Sel.Date
```